# How can I call the WCF service without any authentication?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf

When I run this in Firefox:

```
$.post('http://localhost:54507/Service1.svc/IService1.GetData',{
value:1
},function(){
},);
```

I get a "405 Method Not Allowed" error. How can I allow this call from anywhere without any authentication?

Answer (score 1):

For disable authentication, you have to cahnge setting of your Web Server (IIS for examble). For your web site you have to enable Anonymous Authentication.

Try to open the URI "http://localhost:54507/Service1.svc" on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the web server is not correctly setup for wcf [there are some settings documented on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/31d3f1aa-28b6-4bd7-b031-73b7e7588e6d) that may help.

Answer (score 1):

Please run firebug and have a look at what is attempting to be posted and then set a breakpoint on your svc code...

Answer (score 0):

Is your webserver set to only accept `https` requests?  Making a request using `http` when the resource requires `https` can result in a 405.